# Стоит ли вызывать ServerSocket в потоке-демоне?

Tags: java

Пишу небольшое клиент-серверное приложение с использованием сокетов.
Появился вопрос. Для приема подключений со стороны клиентов на сервере формируется ServerSocket. Для удобства работы с серверной частью выделил его в отдельный поток. Но вот проблема: когда он ожидает нового подключения (serverSocket.accept()) этот поток никак нельзя прервать - он не реагирует на interrapt, т.к. цикл стоит на месте до тех пор, пока не появится новое подключение. Тем самым возникает проблема - главная нить уже отработала (я хочу завершить работу сервера), но т.к. поток с ServerSocket еще жив - программа не завершается. Вопрос по матчасти. Если я сделаю поток с сервер-сокетом демоном, при закрытии основого потока как поведет себя подключение в потоке демоне? Корректно закроется или просто прервется? Код метода run() ниже:

```
public void run() { //основной метод нити
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(settings.getPort())) { //создает серверный сокет
            ConsoleHelper.writeMessage("SocketServer запущен");
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); //слушаем входящие запросы на подключение
                new Handler(socket).start(); //при получении запроса формируем новую нить, отвечающую за работу с клиентом, и запускаем ее
                continue; //после этого снова продолжаем слушать запросы
            }
        } catch (IOException e) { //в случае, если создать серверный сокет не удалось, либо он выкинул исключение во время работы,
            ConsoleHelper.writeMessage("Произошла ошибка работы с сетью!"); //выводится сообщение в консоль
            ConsoleHelper.writeMessage("============================================");
            ConsoleHelper.writeMessage(e.getMessage()); //а так же информация о самом исключении
            ConsoleHelper.writeMessage("============================================");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как вы его прерываете? И зачем у вас return и continue?

Comment: Они действительно не нужны, но на работу в данном случае не влияют.
Вопрос то в другом - если этот код находится в потоке-демоне, при завершении основной нити, поток-демон корректно закроет сокет? (ибо полагаюсь на try-with-resourses)

Comment: так зачем они в коде? Так как вы его прерываете?

Comment: Я его не могу прервать сам - в данном случае проверку на прерывание я могу вставить только в цикл while, и он отработает только после подключения нового клиента. Это не приемлимо. Как еще закрыть поток, кроме как сделать его демоном я не знаю, вот и спрашиваю - корректно ли он завершиться при завершении основного и или нет. И да, спасибо за то, что указали на ненужные операторы, удалил

Comment: лучшим вариантом буде закрытие сокета и тогда поток остановится.

Comment: т.е. предлагаете мне убрать серверсокет из ресурсов в try и сделать закрытие в блоке finally? Спасибо, это более громоздко выйдет, но прервать я действительно смогу закрытием подключения

Comment: просто передайте сокет снаружи в этот поток. И при завершении работы - закройте его.